# Mapping json to Ballerina record

Tags: http, ballerina, ballerina-http

```
    {
        "ID": "2bdaad2e-e6f4-49d1-b737-e0276d8ccc03",
        "name": "simple-config",
        "metadata": {},
        "secret_type": "Opaque",
        "environment_id": "b1402013-b080-488d-858b-dadcb07a551a",
        "data": null
    }
```

Above JSON is the response from an HTTP client. We have an HTTP service and within that service, we call the above HTTP client and prepare a minimized response from the above JSON. The expected minimized response is,

```
    {
        "ID": "2bdaad2e-e6f4-49d1-b737-e0276d8ccc03",
        "name": "simple-config"
    }
```

Please find the relevant code below.

```
public type ResponseDto record {
    string ID;
    string name;
};

isolated resource function get () {
   var httpClient = check getHttpClient();
   string endpoint = string `/v1/external/api`;
   var headers = utils:createHeaders(ctx);
   json response = check httpClient->get(endpoint, headers, targetType = json);
   ResponseDto res = check response.cloneWithType();
   return res;
}
```

Still, I am getting full response and not getting the minimized response. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ResponseDto` can hold additional fields other than `ID` and `name`. That is exactly what happens here as well. `CloneWithType` does not loose data.

```
import ballerina/http;

public type ResponseDtoOpen record {
    string ID;
    string name;
};

public type ResponseDtoClosed record {|
    string ID;
    string name;
|};

service / on new http:Listener(9090) {
    isolated resource function get foo() returns ResponseDtoClosed|error {
        http:Client httpClient = check new ("http://localhost:9090");
        map<string> headers = {};
        ResponseDtoOpen response = check httpClient->/v1/'external/api(headers = headers);
        ResponseDtoClosed res = {ID: response.ID, name: response.name};
        return res;
    }
};
```

In the above code, we are mapping data with the required fields.